# How can I prevent WordPress from adding extra classes to element in the WYSIWYG editor

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

WordPress adds a lot of extra classes and attributes to different elements when creating a post in the WYSIWYG editor. Is there any way to prevent those classes from being added using the **functions.php** file?

In this case, `alignnone size-full wp-image-540` are just extra classes that I don't need. Similarly, I don't want to set fixed `width` and `height` attributes. I am using `my-class` to set a `max-width` to 50% but the image does not stay in its original proportions on resizing the window because WordPress sets the width and height values by itself.

Is there any code that I can write in **functions.php** file to prevent WordPress from automatically applying any kind of attributes and classes on elements?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this will do it:

```
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Try adding that to your functions.php. The functions can be found [here](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/media.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the full functions [here](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/media.php). So just add this to your code

this should **filter** the `get_image_tag_class` and the `__return_empty_string` classes:

`add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string' );`